# Compare 2 arrays for similarity and display the difference in the console

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

```
$(function(){


var x = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
var y = new Array("a", "b", "3", "d", "e");
var str = "";

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        if (x[i] == y[j]) {
            break;
        } else {
            //Check if reach the last element in the array 2
            //If yes, then display that element in array 1 b/c not in array 2

              if (y[j] == y.length - 1) {
                str += x[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(x[i]);



});
```

x[i] is returning undefined which should actually display the different value the is not found in both compared arrays. How do i get the value from x[i]? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to display the list of only the values you put into `str`, try `console.log(str);` For displaying the contents of an array like you're trying to do, use `console.log(x.toString());`

Comment: That just returns all the items in the array. I'd like to display only the items that are different or dont match..

Comment: You are comparing the value of y[j] to the array's length...  Which will almost never be true

Comment: No values are being assigned to 'str' because 'x[i]' is returning undefined.

Comment: How should this be written gary if id like to check and make sure i haven't reached the last item of the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if (y[j] == y.length - 1)` to `if (j == y.length - 1)` so that you are doing a check on the current iterator position instead of y array value.

And change `console.log(x[i]);` to `console.log(str);` so that you output the `str` variable you set in the loop

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable that displays the difference is `str` not `x`.  `x` woudl still hold the array you initially defined as it is not being altered.  `x[i]` is returning undefined because `i` is not defined outside the loop.